# How to use Memcached with PHP7?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, memcached, php-7

I was trying to find any information about using Memcached with PHP7, but I failed. The only valuable information is short `Readme.md` of [php-memcached repo](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/tree/php7).
Unfortunately, its [travis build](https://travis-ci.org/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached) failed as well as [30/126 tests](http://pastebin.com/qxuNh4Ex) on my machine.

However `make install` command was successful and created `memcached.so` file. Does it mean I can use this extension in production or it still has bugs and is not recommended for using?

I will very appreciate any advice or working solution.

Comment: I fixed the travis build ... if you have bugs, report them ... there's no possible way to guess ;)

Comment: @JoeWatkins will follow your advice in a short time, thank you

Comment: Also, they are all experimental tests ... travis wasn't failing because of bugs in php-memcached, just bugs in the build script ... you should be fine.

Comment: @JoeWatkins thank for notice, that's important. Does it mean that current php-memcached#php7 is not covered with tests, so can not considered to be stable?

Comment: No, the failures you have are in tests/experimental, which are not run by CI ... they cover experimental features ...

Comment: One important change in the php7 version of php-memcached is the removal of the $cas_token parameter from the get methods, I've written a post about this: http://developer.procurios.com/post/2016/05/17/Using-Memcached-with-PHP-7

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `php7` branch; [see here](https://travis-ci.org/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/branches), Travis is passing.

This should be the complete set of steps to install the `memcached` extension on a Debian/Ubuntu OS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev libmemcached11 git build-essential

git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached
cd php-memcached
git checkout php7
git pull

/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config

make
sudo make install
```

You may need to change some of the paths if you have them installed at different locations.

Comment: I don't understand what I am meant to do with `/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config` `/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize` does not exist.

Comment: @JamieHutber: "*If the system is missing the phpize command, and precompiled packages (like RPM's) are used, be sure to also install the appropriate devel version of the PHP package as they often include the phpize command along with the appropriate header files to build PHP and its extensions.*" -- http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Comment: @JamieHutber sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev and then /usr/bin/phpize is there

Comment: In my Ubuntu 18.04 setup with PHP7.2 I also had to `apt-get install pkg-config zlib1g-dev` and my `php`, `phpize` and `php-config` were in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 8):

To install memcached on the latest ubuntu for the latest php use:

```
sudo apt-get install php-memcached
```

Comment: If a message error "No Memcached servers added" you need also to install: `sudo apt-get install memcached` and then it works!

Answer (score 4):

For Debian 8 users, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-memcached
```

Comment: Note that the extension version installed is this case is: **3.0.3**. Unfortunately I couldn't use it because it's considered as a new major version and not being supported by some old vendor libraries that check directly on the version number to initialize themselves. In this case the last version it supported was 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question via an issue with getting artisan to work in the Laravel Lumen framework.

I'm using PHP 7. `PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` to be precise.

I found the only solution was to install what appears to be the PHP 5 version* with memcached<sup>†</sup>:

`sudo apt install memcached php-memcached`

---

*

```
php-memcached/xenial,now 2.2.0-51-ge573a6e+2.2.0-2build2 amd64 [installed]
  memcached extension module for PHP5, uses libmemcached
```

<sup>†</sup> If you find you then get the error: `[RuntimeException] Could not establish Memcached connection.`, you need to install the memcached extension as the above `sudo apt install memcached` (if you're on 16.04+, use `apt-get` if < 16.04)

Comment: I literally have no idea why it has -1 @hegez

Comment: I upvoted, also have no idea what the downvote was for

Comment: Also a note, at least for php 7.1 installing `php7.1-memcached` works, but it just points to `php-memcached`, at least on the Ondrej repo that I found described here http://blog.programster.org/debian-8-install-php-7-1