# Does Memecached support PHP 7?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

Like in topic, I cant find answer. Does Memecached support PHP 7.0.12? Or only PHP 5.x version and 6.0.0

Comment: do you mean the other way around? PHP7 to support memcached ?

Comment: also, there is no public release of a PHP version 6

Comment: Yes, PHP7 does support memcached.

Comment: Yes, yes. I want to know that memcached is supported by PHP 7.0.12

Comment: @Jakub Matczak can you write bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure if binaries are already available, so you probably still need to build on your own the `php7` branch in `php-memcached` repository. https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/tree/php7

Comment: @Jakub Matczak  thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Memcached with PHP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374068/how-to-use-memcached-with-php7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, not yet, the current memcache extension doesn't work with the current php 7.

See the actual memcached page here - https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached - where they do indeed say that it currently requires > php 5.2 && < php 6.0