# W3 Total Cache (and Wordpress) not recognizing memcached after installation

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached, w3-total-cache

Ok, so I'm trying to enable the `memcached` mode of the `W3 Total Cache` on my `Wordpress` site to get better performance compared to the `disk` mode I have at the moment.

The `memcached` option in the `Page Cache Method:` drop-down menu of the `W3TC` settings page was greyed out and disabled since `memcached` was not installed in my machine. Thus I followed instructions from [this website](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/memcache/memcache_ubuntu.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374068/how-to-use-memcached-with-php7) and ran the following commands:

```
apt-get -y update && \

apt-get install -y memcached && \
service memcached start

apt-get install -y git nano vim netcat && \
apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev libmemcached11 git build-essential  && \
apt-get install -y pkg-config zlib1g-dev && \

git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached && \
(cd php-memcached && \
git checkout php7 && \
git pull  && \

phpize && \
./configure --with-php-config=php-config && \

make && \
make install)
```

`memcached` is successfully installed and say `echo "stats settings" | netcat localhost 11211` works perfectly, but the problem persists and the `phpinfo()` page doesn't have a section for `memcached`. This is obviously because my Wordpress does NOT yet recognize `memcached` as a possible method for caching stuff.

So, what I'm asking is **how can I make my Wordpress understand that `memcached` is a possible caching method?? :)** Am I missing any configuration step?

I'm using `PhP 7.2.28` and `Wordpress 5.3.2` on `Debian GNU/Linux 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PHP-FPM installed? I've run into issues where I've forgotten to restart it after installing something new.

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of php you are currently using by running the following command,

```
sudo php -v
```

The chances are memchached is not installed on the version of php you are using.

In your case, you need to try the following,

```
sudo apt install php7.2-memcached
```

And reboot server.